# Concatenating in a for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add a new variable to an existing data frame that I have created by reading a dataset. The dataset can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data), but it is in csv format.

```
titanic = data.frame()
titanic = read.table("Titanic.txt", header = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
```

I would like to add a mew variable called x that reads from the `V2` column of this data frame. If the value of `V2` is 1, then the equivalent in x should be "Survived". If it is 0, then x gives "Died".

I decided to construct a simple for loop that uses if statements:

```
for(i in titanic$V2){
  if(i == "1"){
    a<- c(a,"Survived")
  }
  if(i == "0"){
    a <- c(a, "Died")
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting error that says "replacement has xxx rows, data has yyy rows. And it seems that every time I run the program, my variable a is concatenating based on the result from the last run.

I am not sure why variable `a` is not cleared after I re-run the program, and also why the data I am outputting is different from the data I am getting it from.

Comment: Even if Tim gets the code working, I recommend against concatenating piece-wise to a vector in this fashion: it is memory- and speed-inefficient (though perhaps not something you can perceive at small numbers). Especially when you know the exact size, you can preallocate it with `a <- character(nrow(titanic))` *before* the loop, then use `for (i in seq_len(nrow(titanic)))` and `titanic$V2[i] == "1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ifelse` here:

```
titanic$status <- ifelse(titanic$V2, "Survived", "Died")
```

This should work because if `V2` be 1, then it should behave as true, with 0 behaving as false.

As a side note, the following code does in fact work for me:

```
a <- character()
for (i in titanic$V2) {
    if (i == "1") {
    a <- c(a,"Survived")
    }
    if (i == "0") {
        a <- c(a, "Died")
    }
}
titanic$status <- a
```

But I would use `ifelse` for this because it is vectorized.

Comment: thank you! do you see a reason why the concat isn't working?

Comment: @Kat I am playing around with your code now...I will try to "fix" it, but `ifelse` if probably the way to go here.

Comment: Yes, I realized that ifelse is a much better way.

Comment: @Kat I can get your code to work [here](http://rextester.com/EBCTJ51320).  Not sure what you were doing.